# hook_field_validate on unlimited value field

Tags: 7, entities

I've developed my own field type, with its own widget and own formatter etc. This field is a composite field with text fields, radio selectors, and file upload widgets. (The code is 1000+ lines so too long to post here)

I'm just in the process of sorting out the validation and I'm running into a small issue.

Using the field_example.module I've used the `hook_field_validate` and `hook_field_widget_error` together to produce the validation of the elements.

I'm validating one of the textfields in the widget, and it's called `query`. If `query` is empty, then the rest of the fields on this widget is required (e.g. `file upload`, `title override` etc).

This works on limited value fields which don't have an `Add another item` button, and don't get automatically an empty row added on Edit. However on Unlimited value instances, the validator is catching the last empty row which is supposed to get ignored.

The field module has a `hook_field_is_empty` which is working last time I checked. **How can I avoid this extra last empty row from being validated?** [This comment](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/field_example!field_example.module/7#comment-48508) on the API page seems to confirm my problem too.

The code for `hook_field_validate`:

```
function hook_field_validate($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, &$errors) {
  foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
    if(empty($item['solr_query'])) {
      $override = $item['override'];

      $img_preview = $override['img_preview'];
      $img_large = $override['img_large'];
      $ov_title = $override['ov_title'];
      $ov_desc = $override['ov_desc'];

      if(empty($img_preview)) {
        $errors[$field['field_name']][$langcode][$delta][] = array(
          'error' => 'solr_field_img_preview_invalid',
          'message' => t('Preview image is required when no Object reference is supplied.'),
        );
      }

      if(empty($img_large)) {
        $errors[$field['field_name']][$langcode][$delta][] = array(
          'error' => 'solr_field_img_large_invalid',
          'message' => t('Main media is required when no Object reference is supplied.'),
        );
      }

      if(empty($ov_title)) {
        $errors[$field['field_name']][$langcode][$delta][] = array(
          'error' => 'solr_field_ov_title_invalid',
          'message' => t('Title override is required when no Object reference is supplied.'),
        );
      }

      if(empty($ov_desc['value'])) {
        $errors[$field['field_name']][$langcode][$delta][] = array(
          'error' => 'solr_field_ov_desc_invalid',
          'message' => t('Description override is required when no Object reference is supplied.'),
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The code for `hook_field_widget_error`:

```
function hook_field_widget_error($element, $error, $form, &$form_state) {
  switch ($error['error']) {
    case 'solr_field_img_preview_invalid':
      form_error($element['override']['img_preview'], $error['message']);
      break;
    case 'solr_field_img_large_invalid':
      form_error($element['override']['img_large'], $error['message']);
      break;
    case 'solr_field_ov_title_invalid':
      form_error($element['override']['ov_title'], $error['message']);
      break;
    case 'solr_field_ov_desc_invalid':
      form_error($element['override']['ov_desc'], $error['message']);
      break;
  }
}
```

The code for `hook_field_is_empty`:

```
function hook_field_is_empty($item, $field) {
  $empty = TRUE;

  // Trim white space first
  $item['solr_query'] = trim($item['solr_query']);

  if(!empty($item['solr_query'])) {
    $empty = FALSE;
  }
  else {
    // If the Solr Query field is left empty then check
    // all essential override fields are filled in.
    $override = $item['override'];

    $img_preview = $override['img_preview'];
    $img_large = $override['img_large'];
    $ov_title = $override['ov_title'];
    $ov_desc = $override['ov_desc'];

    if($img_preview && $img_large && !empty($ov_title) && !empty($ov_desc['value'])) {
      $empty = FALSE;
    }
  }

  return $empty;
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same problem on a custom field.

Comment: @DaveBruns not cleanly. I just called a custom `_mymodule_reduce_empty_items($items)` function from inside `hook_field_validate` as the first thing that the validate does. The reduce empty function simply loops through the items, and if there's any records that have all the fields empty get `unset()` from the `$items` array

Comment: yes, that makes sense. I ended up just letting empty rows fall through validation entirely. I'm not sure where they get cleaned up(?), but they don't seem to be saved to the database.